# Creating a "this month" query rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, date, activerecord, group-by

I am trying to create a query to record my submissions for this month in my controller using the following code:

```
 @today = Time.now

 @thismonth = @today.month

 @nextmonth = @thismonth + 1

 @submissions = SubmissionLocation.includes(:submission).where(location_id: current_agent.Company_Business_Location, location_id: 2134).map(&:submission)

 @submissions_by_group = @submissions.group_by { |m| m.Max_move_in_date.beginning_of_month}.sort_by{:Max_move_in_date}

 @submission_this_month = @submissions_by_group.where(:Max_move_in_date => @thismonth)
```

It seems to be throwing a nomethod error for the where condition in the @submission_this_month instance variable. I understand that it is most likely because my data is now in a hash format, so in that case, how I would I then query it?

Comment: Have you looked into [select](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Hash.html#method-i-select)?

Comment: If you actually want to group the records by month effectivly you can do by extracting the month from the timestamp. For example on postgres you would use `.group("extract(month from submission_locations.Max_move_in_date )")`. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-datetime.html

Comment: You are also querying from the wrong model. Since the end result that you want is a bunch of Submission records you should be querying Submission and joining SubmissionLocation with conditions on the join table. I would start over and rethink your approach. To avoid a X&Y question situation you way want to edit the question so that it gives an example of the existing data and the desired output instead.